# How to use ServiceCompat?

Tags: android, android-service, android-support-library

I am trying to create a local private Service, which would constantly run in background, scan for bluetooth (using [BLE Wrapper](https://developer.bluetooth.org/Pages/Bluetooth-Smart-Developers.aspx)) and post notifications - when a device with certain address (passed from Activity to the Service as string through [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)) is around.

(Also I'd like my service to start up automatically at boot, so I have added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

to AndroidManifest.xml).

So here is my class:

```
import android.support.v4.app.ServiceCompat;

public class ScanService extends ServiceCompat {
    public ScanService() {
        super("ScanService");
    }
}
```

It does not compile with the following error:

> The constructor ServiceCompat(String) is undefined

Then I try:

```
import android.support.v4.app.ServiceCompat;

public class ScanService extends ServiceCompat {
    public ScanService() {
        super();
    }
}
```

It does not compile with the following error:

> The constructor ServiceCompat() is not visible

Finally I try:

```
import android.support.v4.app.ServiceCompat;

public class ScanService extends ServiceCompat {
    public ScanService() {
    }
}
```

It does not compile with the following error:

> Implicit super constructor ServiceCompat() is not visible. Must explicitly invoke another constructor

So how should I please extend [ServiceCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ServiceCompat.html) properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't extend `ServiceCompat`. You extend `Service`.

If you look at [the JavaDocs for `ServiceCompat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ServiceCompat.html), you will notice that it has only one thing: a `START_STICKY` constant as a `public static int`. That's it. Since it is `public static`, you do not need a subclass to reference that constant. And, since that constant is defined on `Service` since API Level 5, you probably do not need `ServiceCompat` at all.